# Rails Action Fails Upon Second Call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chat

I am writing a chat page in a rails project I am working on. I have a sort of side bar next to the chat window so users can easily switch between conversations. I have been wanting to re-implement the page with ajax, but before I do there is a bug I need to work out. When I click one of the sidebar user buttons, the conversation changes, when I click the button of the user I was speaking to previously again, the conversation doesn't switch. I have an action I defined as flop, that when called changes the recipient user of the conversation. Like I said, I can call the action once for each user, but when trying to return to an already viewed conversation, the display doesn't change.

Here is the controller:

```
    class ChatsController < ApplicationController
     $messeges = Array.new(10, " ")
def new
    $messeges = Array.new
    if $ruser != nil
    $messeges = Array.new
    Chat.all.each_with_index do |i, index|
        if i.recipient == current_user.id && i.sender == $ruser.id
            $messeges.push([i.content, "to"])
        end
        if i.recipient == $ruser.id && i.sender == current_user.id
            $messeges.push([i.content, "from"])
        end
    end
    end
    $chat_users = Array.new
    User.all.each do |user|
        if user != nil && current_user != nil
        if user.game_id == current_user.game_id && user.id != current_user.id
            $chat_users.push(user.username)
        end
        end
    end
    @chat = Chat.new
end

def create
    if $ruser != nil
    @chat = Chat.new(chat_params)
    @chat.recipient = $ruser.id
    @chat.sender = current_user.id
    @chat.save
    end
    redirect_to "/comms/new"
end

def flop
    $ruser = nil
    $ruser = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to "/comms/new"
end

private
    def chat_params
        params.require(:chat).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

Here is the view for the new action, which is where I call flop:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Battleriskopoloy - Communications</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <div id="heading_1" align="center">
            <br><span id="title"><strong>[ . . . Communications . . . ]</strong></span>
        </div><br>
        <div id="sidebar"><br>
            <% $chat_users.each do |user| %>
            <% user = User.find_by_username(user) %>
            <%= button_to user.username, flop_chat_path(user), :class => "select", :method => :get  %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <div id="display">
            <% $messeges.each do |i| %>
                <% if i[1] == "from" %>
                <p style="color:#000000; text-align:right; margin-right:5%;font-family:courier"><%= i[0] %></p>
                <br>
                <% else %>
                <p style="color:#FF0000; text-align:left; margin-left:5%; font-family:courier"><%= i[0] %></p>
                <br>
                <%end%>
            <%end%>
        </div>
        <div id="textfield">
            <%= form_for(@chat) do |f| %>
            <%= f.text_field :content, id: "compose" %>
            <br>
            <br>
            <%= f.submit "Send Messege", id: "submit" %>
        <% end %>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the chance that this is involved, here is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
 resources :users
 resources :games
 resources :forts
 resources :chats do
     member do
         get :flop
     end
 end
 match '/forts/create',  to: 'forts#create',            via: 'post'
  match '/comms/new',  to: 'chats#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/comms',  to: 'chats#show',            via: 'get'
  match '/join_game',  to: 'users#edit',            via: 'get'
  match '/new_game',  to: 'games#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'home#home'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Thanks so much for the help,

Alex

Comment: Where on your page do you assign the `:id` you use in `flop` (`params[:id]`)?

Comment: I believe that is taken from the call based on a certain user. When I write flop_chat_path(user) it infers the object's id should be params(:id). I could be wrong though, and that may very we'll be the problem. Thanks for looking

Comment: You really, *really* don't want to be using global variables like that